# Eclipse freezes with phrase "Updating Debug Browser" with enabled xDebug (for debugging php) every time when I open phpmyadmin

Tags: php, eclipse, phpmyadmin, xdebug

When I open phpmyadmin (in firefox) and log in to it I get opened window in eclipse "Path Mapping - Select Local Resource" with two options one of which is `"Get content from the server for the following path:"` and input with `"/usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php"`. At the bottom right corner of eclipse there is a message `"Searching for local file"`. If I am lucky I check that option, press "OK" (another button is "Stop Debugger") and phpmyadmin opens and eclipse continue to work. But in most cases eclipse freeze with phrase `"Updating Debug Browser"` and I can't do anything. I am using xDebug for debugging php scripts.

How to fix that?

Comment: Looks like you open phpmyadmin when debugging is active. PDT is trying to find source code during debugging. I'm also afraid you ave "Break at first line" active.

Comment: @zulus, yes, I do.

Comment: In general debugging without connected sources is uncommon practice. Anyway make sure "Break at first line" is disabled, you can also disable and close those views. You can also report bug on GitHub.com/eclipse/pdt

Comment: @zulus, "Break at first line" is disabled. I don't want to debug phpmyadmin and want to disable `"/usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php"` for debugger but didn't find a way.

Comment: @zulus, also I click 5 times on "Stop Debugger" to open phpmyadmin page.

Comment: @zulus, but when I click "Ok" button at least I can work with phpmyadmin in browser after that. And when I click "Stop Debugger"  I see the same window in eclipse with the same button  "Stop Debugger" each time when I open any table in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Disabling Debug output and Browser output worked for me. http://www.jochenhebbrecht.be/site/2010-12-03/drupal/eclipse-disable-debug-output-and-browser-output